# Memory card on iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory

I have an sd converter for my iPad but can't find anything like it for my phone?  Plan on using it to view shots from a trailcam while in the woods

Answer (score 1):

Are you mean this thing:http://www.amazon.co.uk/iPad-camera-connection-USB-Adapter-reader/dp/B004R4NLJC.  It only support iPad, not include iPhone, and I searched for iPhone SD card reader, there is no result.